# Making emacs to highlight postgresql syntax by default

Tags: emacs, plpgsql, postgresql

I use emacs for editing my sql code. I work 99% of time on postgresql plpgsql code. All my files with extension .sql contain postgresql. I'm curious is there a way to set *sql-highlight-postgres-keywords* SQL highlighting default instead of ANSI SQL, because it's pretty annoying to switch mode every time I open a file.

Comment: Is `sql-highlight-postgres-keywords` a variable? I can't find it in Emacs 23. I used `M-x sql-mode` which seemed to work, but that was just once-off.

Comment: I use sql-highlight-<db>-keywords in sql-mode to change syntax highlighting depending on DB. if you're not in sql-mode you will not be able to use it.

Comment: ^ Thanks. Yes, it works in sql-mode :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Usually in emacs, if you want to change the settings every time some mode is opened, you use a hook. Something similar to this should work:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
             '("\\.psql$" . (lambda ()
                              (sql-mode)
                              (sql-highlight-postgres-keywords))))
```

Answer (score 20):

If you need to work with different databases, rather than using a hook to always switch to PostgreSQL highlighting when you open a .sql file, you can use Emacs' file variables feature to set the product on a file-by-file basis.

For example, if the first line of your .sql file is

```
-- -*- mode: sql; sql-product: postgres; -*-
```

sql-mode will automatically use PostgreSQL highlighting.

Full details on Emacs file variables [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html#File-Variables) (you can also set them in a block anywhere in the file), and the list of product names is probably eaiest found by doing `M-x sql-set-product`, backspacing the `ansi` default, and hitting TAB to see the completion list.  Examples are "mysql", "oracle", "sqlite", etc (about a dozen in my install).